# I have a difficulty in converting blob image into some extensions like jpg or png

Tags: python, mysql, flask, web, wtforms

**main.py**

```
@app.route('/products/<name>')
def products(name):
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    query = 'SELECT duty FROM staff WHERE name = %s'
    cursor.execute(query,(name,))
    cuisine_type = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    query = 'SELECT * from cuisines WHERE type = %s'
    cursor.execute(query,(cuisine_type,))
    datas = cursor.fetchall()
    
    for data in datas:
        image_file = data[3]
        image_real = base64.decodebytes(data[3])
      
    return render_template('products.html',image_real=image_real,name=name,cuisine_type=cuisine_type,datas=datas)

@app.route('/product_edit/<name>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def product_edit(name):
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    query = 'SELECT duty FROM staff WHERE name = %s'
    cursor.execute(query,(name,))
    cuisine_type = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    form = Products(CombinedMultiDict((request.files, request.form)))
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        item = form.item.data
        price = form.price.data
        f = form.image.data
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        if os.path.exists('photos') == False:
            os.mkdir('photos')
        else:
            pass
        f.save(os.path.join(
            UPLOAD_FOLDER,filename
        ))
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        query = 'INSERT INTO cuisines(type,item,price,img) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)'
        values = (cuisine_type,item,price,filename)
        cursor.execute(query,values)
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
##        return 'Success'
        return redirect(url_for('products',name=name,cuisine_type=cuisine_type))
    return render_template('product_edit.html',cuisine_type=cuisine_type,name=name,form=form)
```

**models.py**

```
class Products(FlaskForm):
  
    item = StringField('Item',[validators.Length(max=100)])
    price = DecimalField('Price per unit', validators=[validators.Optional()], places=1)
    image = FileField('image',validators=[FileRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Add')
```

**products.html**

```
{% for data in datas %} 
            <tr>
                    
                    <td>{{ data[1] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data[2] }}</td>
                    <td><img src=image_real></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="" id="view_btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View</button></a>
                        <a href="" id="edit_btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button></a>
                        <a href="" id="del_btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
                    </td>
               
                </th>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

My target is to show the image that stored in the database phpmyAdmin on the table of html template by using `data[3]` to represent. However when I run the program the image could not show up. How can I convert the blob property into jpg or png so the image could be shown on the html webpage? Is there any methods to represent the image filename by using for loop `data`? I would like to show the specific images accordingly from the database. For the encoding part I may ask how to use for loop to loop over each binary data to convert all of them into image filenames so as to show up the image on the web template?

[Here is the screenshot of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU5QB.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
    image_file = data[3]
    image_real = base64.decodebytes(data[3])
```

If you have base64 encoded image, it is possible to use it directly in `<img>` tag, however you would need to know its type. Consider following example, which has 5x5 blue squared `png` image inserted this way

```
<html>
<head><title>Blue square</title></head>
<body>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAIAAAACDbGyAAAAHUlEQVQIHU3BsQEAAAABoPx/NKsKdUKdUCfUCXUG4V8FAbQndsYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="blue square">
</body>
</html>
```

If you do not know type of image stored take look at `imghdr` built-in module.

Comment: Where to find ```iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAIAAAACDbGyAAAAHUlEQVQIHU3BsQEAAAABoPx/NKsKdUKdUCfUCXUG4V8FAbQndsYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=``` and why the code is so long?

Comment: @DominicSham this is base64 encoded `png` image file, if you want to run my example with another image you need image file and tool to base64-encode it. You might use Ubuntu's  [base64](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/base64.1.html) or python's built-in `base64` module or some online tool (search for *base64 online encoder*). Due to how base64 encoding works (if you want to know more see RFC 3548) length of output is prortional to size (number of bytes) of input.

Comment: so where can I search the code for my photos?

Comment: @DominicSham your code suggest that you already have base64-encoded files in your database

Comment: my encoded files are stored in the database screenshot so how can I call them to show on webpage?